# Is a SqlServer View always up to date?

Tags: sql-server, view

Will a sqlserver view always be up to date or can there be a delay on it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on the [transaction isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) level the view runs at.  By default, views run at `READ COMMITTED`.  The view will return only committed data.  As long as your view consists of only one SQL statement, and doesn't call user defined functions or extended procedures, it will be consistent.

But views can also run at a more risky isolation level.  For example, this view specifies `nolock` so it runs at `READ UNCOMMITTED`:

```
create view dbo.MyView
as select * from dbo.MyTable with (nolock)
```

This view can return values that are part of a transaction that will be rolled back (dirty read.)  This transaction isolation level trades consistency for performance.

Answer (score 4):

a non-indexed view intrinsically can not store out of date data, it is ethereal and any query against it is really hitting the underlying table.

An indexed view does store it's own copy, but in the query plans you will see any insertion / update / deletion also includes the relevant change to the view so the data remains consistent.

Answer (score 2):

They are always up to date. A view is not a persisted object. When you query a view, you are actually querying the underlying tables etc. that make up the view. Therefore, your views will be as up to date as your tables.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that an Indexed View however, is a persisted/materialised object.

Answer (score 1):

view is providing upto date information. but some scenarios it will fail i.e when ever bulk data is inserted into our table then it will not updates base table data to view.

to over come the above problem u need to use sp_refreshview 'ur view name'

Answer (score 0):

A typical view (non-indexed / non-materialized) is just an alias for a SELECT.  It can't be out of date any more than a SELECT can be.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that views can indeed return eroneous data when retrieving data from a different database. For example, in my setup I have a view that does a simple select from a table on another db:

```
SELECT status FROM otherdb.dbo.mytable_t
```

and this returns:

NULL
ACCEPTED
AWAITRTR
IMPORTOK
IMPORTPB
INPROGRE
REJECTED

However running SELECT status FROM mytable_t on otherdb returns:

ACTIVE
AFS
CHANGE
DRAFT
PENDCONF
PENDINIT
REVIEW
TERM

The only way to ensure the view returns the same data as the SELECT in this scenario is to drop and recreate the view.

I have seen this quite a few times on SQL Server 2000, 2005 and 2008.